# How to Update the content of my app with out the user updating the app version

Tags: android

Hey guys am a new programmer for android development, and i was doing a project that needs the content to be updated more frequently an i don't know how to do that.

will you help me please. The contents i need to update are like texts as well as pictures

Help please.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please elaborate your problem and also state what you've done to solve your problem and where you are stuck. Visit [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) or have a [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about community and the kind of questions expected. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update data from database, you will need to use thread and perhaps a timer would help too which will trigger the thread to get data from database.
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607053/update-data-to-server-in-the-background-android) will help you to implement threading. And inside the thread, you will connect with remote server's API to get the data you wanted.

Comment: Oh thank you, I will definitely read the link you sent me. Can u also send me a link or something that shows in detail that show how to connect to a database server so that i can update the app more frequently. My questions may be to elementary. Tnx very much

Comment: here, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm and https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/php-android-tutorial-part-1/